# Break long algorithm in pages

Tags: latex

I have an algorithm defined with `algorithm` environment defined by [`algorithm2e` LaTeX package (v5.2)](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), like this:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \Begin{
  % Many...
  % Many...
  % ...
  % lines.
  }
\end{algorithm}[H]
```

Suppose that this is a very long algorithm.

Is there a way to break algorithm to fit in many pages?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MattTimmermans Ok, move my question to Tex, but please do not close it.